# Pushing to Array Overwrites Similar Entries

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Basically what I am trying to do is grab an object from one array, append a property to that object, and then push that new object to a new array. The problem is once I push that object to the new array (with the new, different property), it overwrites all previous objects in the new array that have similar properties to this new object, despite me altering the property before pushing.

What should be:

```
{propA: "Name", propB: "Age", propC: "Location1"}
{propA: "Name", propB: "Age", propC: "Location2"}
{propA: "Name", propB: "Age", propC: "Location3"}
```

Becomes:

```
{propA: "Name", propB: "Age", propC: "Location3"}
{propA: "Name", propB: "Age", propC: "Location3"}
{propA: "Name", propB: "Age", propC: "Location3"}
```

Here you can find the code, with the relevant lines highlighted in yellow: http://pastie.org/private/ym8dbp1jpjwyrgbpdubk3a#47-52,59,67,85-86

And here is the console output to show that the correct information is being pushed to `cliAllow` but are being overwritten: http://pastie.org/private/g3480a91tr3jvhftxaclq

**Edit:** Here is a simplified version in JSBin: http://jsbin.com/kanibo/2/edit?js,console

I am re-writing this code from my old code which was my first time writing in javascript so please excuse what may be incorrect programming methods elsewhere in the code.

Your help is greatly appreciated. I've been trying to debug this for almost a week and I am heavily exhausted.

Comment: That's some complicated code.  I copied that code into Apps Script and can't even get a couple lines to run without an error.  So, maybe you have even more code?  Have you been using the debugger and breakpoints?  [Apps Script Debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)  `Logger.log` statements are great, but the debugger shows the value of every single variable in your code simultaneously.

Comment: @SandyGood Here is a link to the sheet with some data that you can copy into your sheet: http://goo.gl/xljCcS & here is a link to the other parts of the code not included in the original link: http://pastie.org/private/vso5ubfrxdelcdouvmfma I will try the running with breakpoints and the debugger, but I already know what is happening - just not why. It makes perfect sense to me, but when it runs it does not turn out how it should.

Comment: The `mlstnParties` array has a hard coded index of zero for the first dimension:  `mlstnParties[0][mlstnCol]`.  That will never reference any other data than the first element in the array.  The first element is the first row that `getValues()` returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not pushing copies of the objects to the array `cliAllow`, but you're pushing references to the same object(s).

So let's go through the first iteration of the outer `while` loop to see what the result is:

```
cliAllow.push(arr[4]);
cliAllow.push(arr[4]);
cliAllow.push(arr[4]);
```

Now, `cliAllow.length` is 3, with indexes from 0 to 2, but you have 3 array items pointing to the very same object (the last one in the `notPassed` array, since you're counting backwards.)

So, `cliAllow[0], cliAllow[1], cliAllow[2]` all now references the same object.

That means, when you're setting the `party` property, you're change the same object 3 times:

```
cliAllow[2].party = "NT";
cliAllow[1].party = "VL";
cliAllow[0].party = "LF";
```

You're essentially doing this:

```
var obj = {milestone: "Mlstn4", client: "Client2", trade: "Trade3", units: "25.0", party: "B"};

obj.party = "NT";
obj.party = "VL";
obj.party = "LF";
```

As you can see, you're writing to the same property on the same object 3 times here, which means it will be set to the last value you give it (`"LF"` in this case).

In your code, you have 5 items in the `notPassed` array, but instead of 15 different objects, you have only 5, and each one of those 5 objects gets its `party` property set to the last value in the `mlstnParties` array.

One way of solving this is to make a copy function:

```
function copy(obj) {
  var cp = {};
  for (var o in obj) {
      cp[o] = obj[o];
  }
  return cp;
}
```

See it in action here: http://jsbin.com/kibeba/2/edit

Comment: I see what you've done here, however it is basically what I have done in my code already, where `arr = arr` and `otherArr = cliAllow`. I have not used the `.map` function because I do not need to loop through the array, just add a property to a single entry.

Comment: OK. Could you provide a more stripped down version of your issue on e.g. jsbin.com?

Comment: I have added a simplified version in JSBin: http://jsbin.com/kanibo/3/edit?js,console

Comment: @Rawrcasm OK, I have edited my answer to explain why your code isn't working as intended.

Comment: I have reviewed your answer and it ties along with more research I've done today that basically stated what you said about them not being copies, but instead references. He went on to show how using a constructor and a literal assignment of the property would alleviate the issue, however when I tried adapting it into my code I am still getting the same problem somehow. It's only my second time using a constructor.. do you think you could have a look? [http://jsbin.com/kanibo/10/edit?js,console](http://jsbin.com/kanibo/10/edit?js,console)

Comment: Here's my version of it: http://jsbin.com/losusa/1/edit?js,console. 
There's absolutely no need for any constructor function. You can just use the copy function I added in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am elated right now.. so much stress finally relieved. Who knew it would end up being such a simple, elegant solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this out in order to understand what the code is doing, and to confirm that I understand what it's doing.

When I ran the function named `gatherResponses()` it put 65 objects into the array `notPassed` (with the data you provided).  The object properties are:

```
{client:"Client 1", trade:"Batch 21", units:250, milestone:"Milestone 18", due:(new Date(1423803600000))}
```

Then that array of objects, named `notPassed` gets passed to the function `checkThresholds()`

Then the elements (which are objects) of the `notPassed` array (now named `arr`) get pushed into another array named `cliAllow`.

```
cliAllow[cliAllow.length] = arr[arrLen];
```

Then a particular object in the new array gets accessed and the `party` property is assigned a value.

```
cliAllow[cliAllow.length-1].party = mlstnParties[0][mlstnCol];
```

The while loop is counting down from the biggest number to zero.  Because of that, the variable `arrLen` is going from the highest number to the zero.  This means that the array is being processed from the last element (last object) to the first object.  It's not working "front to back", but backwards from the last to the first element (object) in the array.

In the original objects inside the `notPassed` array, there is no `party` property.  So, it the `party` property that is getting added.

The `party` property is getting it's value from the `mlstnParties` array.  That array is getting it's value from the spreadsheet.

If the `party` property isn't getting the correct values assigned to it, I'm wondering if there's a problem from the `mlstnParties` array?  The `mlstnParties` array is a two dimensional array.  The first dimension is each row, the second dimension is an array of all the values in that row.

This is the line of code I'm questioning:

```
cliAllow[cliAllow.length-1].party = mlstnParties[0][mlstnCol];
```

The row index is hard coded as zero.  The code is never referencing any other row than whatever row got put into the first index of the array.  I would think that you would want the first index parameter to be a variable that changes.

Comment: excellent write-up. You've pretty much nailed it up until the last section. The `party` property is being correctly assigned, and the hard-coded 0-index is intentional - that is, when you use `getValues()` a 2d array is returned (rows, columns) but in this case there is only 1 row so I keep the row-index at 0 to iterate through the columns, in turn gathering the parties. If you see in first half of the log, each party is being correctly assigned each time. The problem is that once it pushes to `cliAllow`, all of the object pushed before it with similar properties are overwritten.